# Large table, surrounding divs with backgrounds won't repeat

Tags: css, background, repeat

I have a 1000px wide page that holds output in a table that is much wider than the rest of the page. I have no problem with scrolling horizontally to read all of the data but the backgrounds of the surrounding divs like the header and footer are not repeating out with the large table.

I read some tips about adding "display:inline-block" to a div around the large table, but I still haven't found a solution.

Help is much appreciated.

```
<div id="top_ad">
</div>
<div id="header">
</div>
<table>
THIS IS THE HUGE TABLE
</table>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

The header div's background is repeating out because I have the image set as the BODY's background as opposed to the "header" div. However the "top_ad" and "footer" div's backgrounds stop at 1000px. My CSS below:

```
body {
background:url(/images/header_background_repeat.jpg) repeat-x 0 110px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
color:#262626;
text-align:center;
}

#top_ad {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background: #0f3245;
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 6px solid #C9660D;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Probably your header and footer divs are only as wide as the page. Use Firebug or some other developer insight, click over the part where you want it to be showing, and see if it's the header or footer div element you expect.

Comment: Thanks Matt. The two divs that are giving me problems are currently set with 'width:100%'. I can increase that, but then the content gets pushed out to the left.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need a scrollable div to contain your table. Here I use width 100% but you may want to use a width = to the width of your page.

http://jsfiddle.net/XXhzp/

```
<div id="tablecontainer" style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
    <table>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. this works. but the client actually wants the table to display normally while the entire page scrolls. that's why i need the backgrounds of those divs to repeat out. i know it doesn't sound pretty hehe.

Comment: @user1165358 - ahh, I see now. Yeah this "bug" drives me crazy. I see it every now and then and I can never remember the fix. Adding min-width somewhere does it I think. Let me think...

Comment: @user1165358 - Okay, I dug up the old SO question that addressed this, but I still don't like the solution. Basically you add min-width to the body and set it equal to the width of your table. But this is dependent on you having some idea what the width of that table is. I can give you a js solution if you need it. Not ideal I know, but I can't think of anything else. http://jsfiddle.net/XXhzp/1/

Comment: Yea I see why you don't like the solution. It works, but it also causes the centering of the page to adapt to the new width, so on load, you're looking at the far right of the table with no nav or anything hehe. I'm still at it, any new ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

append a width of 100% to your body

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a container div around everything in the page. Presumably, that div will take on the width of the child table and will then confer that width to the other divs if they are set to 100%.